# How to mock xmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, rhino-mocks

I trying to remove my xmlSerializer dependency, and use a xmlSerializer mock using rhinomocks. But it seems like IXmlSerializer doesnt get implimented by XmlSerializer. Am I wrong? How do I inject my xmlserializer dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do write a wrapper around the XmlSerializer and use the wrapper as in

```
 public class XmlSerializerWrapper:IXmlSerializerWrapper
  {
       private XmlSerializer _serializer;

      //implement some methods that you need from XmlSerializer
  }
```

Comment: Ideologically I am grossed out by this, but this is so effective, simple, and universally applicable, I cant help but to love this solution.